# How to Load Nested navigation properties in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

If we have some nested collection (navigation property) in the entity model and this navigation also has a navigation property, what can you load using Entity Framework with minimal performance penalty?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

as use see the name of the navigation matters

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ThenInclude` to load nested relations

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var customers = context.Customers
        .Include(i => i.Invoices)
            .ThenInclude(it => it.Items)
        .ToList();
}
```